# How to use Ajax to render liquid code and output as HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I'm working on a mini cart on my Shopify site and using ajax to add items to the cart. For each line item I need to get metafield data, but jquery won't allow me to do this.

- I have all the code for my line items in a section line-item-list.liquid
- I'm trying to use ajax to get the line-item-list.liquid using Shopify's section-render (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/section-rendering)

Below is the code for my mini-cart and the line-item-list.liquid. The problem is that this code is returning as a JSON string, but I need it to render as HTML.

Is it possible to use Ajax to render the liquid code and output it as HTML?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

mini-cart.liquid

```
<div class="add-line-item">Add Line Item</div>
<div class="line-items"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-line-item').on('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/?sections=line-item-list',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          $('.line-items').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.error("Error fetching line-item-list content:", errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

sections/line-item-list.liquid

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.product.metafields.custom.some-metafield == true %}
    {% assign is_metafield = true %}
  {% endif %}
  ...other code here
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: AJAX is for making requests, not for rendering something - so **no, not possible**

Comment: Check this https://shopify.dev/docs/api/section-rendering

Comment: @Justinas it is possible using Shopify's section-rendering, I figured it out and posted a comment with the update code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to change the URL to url: '/?section_id=line-item-list'

Updated code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-line-item').on('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/?sections=line-item-list',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          $('.line-items').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.error("Error fetching line-item-list content:", errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```